# Image Text Recognition detects specfic font in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Is there's specific text font detection in flutter? I've been wondering since I want to detect text with this font only named`(ocra)` because sometimes the numbers 6 and 8 recognize as b and 6, so I came up with the solution of getting the specific font detection, it is possible? thanks in advance

[image]

Current : Result

[image]

```
  PickedFile _image;
  Future scanText() async {
    final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage =
        FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(File(_image.path));
    final TextRecognizer textRecognizer =
        FirebaseVision.instance.textRecognizer();
    final VisionText visionText =
        await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage);

    for (TextBlock block in visionText.blocks) {
      for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
        _text += line.text + '\n';
      }
    }

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Details(_text)));
  }
```

Comment: Side note: The package you are using is discontinued. Consider using `https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit` instead. Though, the API does not seem to include options for specific fonts, but you might be able to create a custom model for the specific task

Comment: Train your own model :)